# Swift 2 Table View Cell with Hyperlink

Tags: xcode, swift, uitableview, swift2, xcode7

I've created a `UITableView` with different Sections and cells like: "Follow us on Instagram" or "Like us on Facebook".
This cells should have a link to each page.
I tried this:

```
@IBAction func WebLink(sender: AnyObject) {
if let url = NSURL(string: "http://...") {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
}
}
```

But i can't link the `@IBAction` with the Cell...

It should look like this and on every Cell should be a Hyperlink.

[image]

Comment: Hey there, there's no need for an IBAction when working with a tableview cell. ...Are you working with a cell? Also, Can we get more details? What are you trying to do? Visit the link within the application? Move from your current application to safari and load the website? Move to the associated app? Lots of questions here.

Comment: The links should open in Safari after clicking on the cell.
For Example:
"Follow us on Facebook" - If the User clicks on the cell, safari should open with the facebook fanpage.
Moving to Facebook App would be better i think... But i don't know how to do.

Comment: Okay I get it now. I'll include code for both.

Comment: Follow up questions: Are these simple text that take advantage of being clickable (URLEncoded) or are these UILabels? Also, do you want the text to be displayed as a literal hyperlink (in blue?). The picture above doest seem to indicate as much but I want to double check.

Comment: You maybe know the Swift Explaining App in Appstore its called "Swifty" 
If you click there on Setting you see what i meant. I want it exactly like that.

Answer (score 2):

You can directly use:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
     let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as UITableViewCell!
     // launch your func WebLink with the currentCell
     ...
}
```

Comment: This answer is what I lean to but I'm cautious in assuming what I think the user wants to do.

Comment: @AlessandroOmano TIL that you don't have to give people the entire answer in order to help them. Thanks Alessandro.

Comment: @Leon - Depend by your cell class type, if you use UITableViewCell or custom cell..

Comment: I am using a UITableView Cell with a UILabel on it. Not custom cell.

Comment: I've uploaded a screenshot.https://s32.postimg.org/8yqkl0jgl/Bildschirmfoto_2016_06_21_um_17_00_59.png

Comment: Okay now we're looking. Working on an answer.

Comment: You do not need to redeclare indexPath! It is already given within the function's parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not finding anything that would allow us to do so with a simple label. But there is a library available that does so in github. It seems you can't do so with a simple label in Swift. However, there is a library called TTTAttributedLabel that I think does what you're looking for. Here's a link to the library: https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel

```
@IBOutlet var exampleLabel: TTTAttributedLabel!

    //...

let exampleString: NSString = "My super cool link"
exampleLabel.delegate = self
exampleLabel.text = exampleString as String
var range : NSRange = exampleString.rangeOfString("link")
exampleLabel.addLinkToURL(NSURL(string: "http://www.stackoverflow.com")!, withRange: range)

func attributedLabel(label: TTTAttributedLabel!, didSelectLinkWithURL url: NSURL!) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
}
```

Side note: Did not ever imagine I'd miss Objective-C. I'll update with a  Swift 3.0 answer if this is what you were looking for.